# Does php evaluate the second argument of an or statement if the first evaluates to false?

Tags: php, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

So my question is about the behaviour of php in the case of an or statement taking two functions. When the first function already evaluates to true, is there a chance that the second function will still be executed?

I hope that the following code can clarify what I mean:

```php
$dbh->startTransaction();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM foo WHERE id=:id");

$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if (!$stmt->execute() || !bar($id)) {
    $dbh->rollBack();
}
```

What I want to be sure of is that `bar()` is *never* called when `$stmt` fails to execute.

I know that in some languages the or statement would return true the moment `!$stmt->execute()` evaluated to true and that I could be sure that `bar()` would not be called unless `!$stmt->execute()` evaluated to false (meaning `$stmt->execute()` evaluated to true and the query was sucessful).

Do I have this certainty in php or is it possible that the server would evaluate `$stmt->execute()` and `bar($id)` simultaneously or in the reverse order and in such a way wreak havoc on my database?

I am assuming I would be able to apply whatever answer I get here to an and statement as well. If that is not the case, please tell me.

Comment: You mean if the first evaluates as true? Then no, the second won't be triggered. As soon as it finds a match, it's done.

Comment: `||` will stop as soon as one the operators is true, so if `execute()` is false, then it would automatically skip the `!bar()`.  The only thing is that using `!` can make the condition very confusing to maintain.  You could replace it with `$stmt->execute() && bar($id)` which means that the the `bar()` part will not be done if the `execute()` fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logical operator **`||`** means it won't execute the second expression if the first evaluates to true. If you are using **`or`**,**`|`** then the second expression going to be evaluated even if the first evaluates to true.

```
if ($expression || $expression) {
    //
}
```

here, if the first expression evaluates to true, then **`||`** won't let the second expression to evaluate and flow continues in `if` block. The second expression only be evaluated when the first becomes `false`.

This boolean operation is exactly as explain in major programming languages, not only in php. If you want to look in depth, please visit [Logical Operators in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) Doc.

[image: Logical Operators]

The logical operator **`||`** has **left associativity** as per [Precedance Rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), states the left expression always evaluates first, if left fails then right will be evaluated.